# how i can play the audio when i write any number by javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

i have small project in middel of the window textfield when i put the number i need to call by audio what number i write it on texfield for example i wrote number : 1 enter and the audio is working for one time is play agian when i wrote the same number or another number and stop it  etc...

i have searching the code what is responsibility for like this project but i just a found play audio

```
//this the text field what i have to write the number on it 
//(numberscreen)
//screen1,screen2...etc it's for passing the old number from number 
//screen 

@FXML
private TextField numberscreen;

@FXML
public void screeninsert() {
    play();
    String enteredText = numberscreen.getText();
    String enteredText1 = screen1.getText();
    String enteredText2 = screen2.getText();
    String enteredText3 = screen3.getText();
    String enteredText4 = screen4.getText();
    String enteredText5 = screen5.getText();
    String enteredText6 = screen6.getText();
    numberscreen.clear();
    screen1.setText(enteredText);
    screen2.setText(enteredText1);
    screen3.setText(enteredText2);
    screen4.setText(enteredText3);
    screen5.setText(enteredText4);
    screen6.setText(enteredText5);
    screen7.setText(enteredText6);

 }

public void AudioPlay(){
URL url = 
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("audio/1.wav");
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url); 
AudioFormat littleEndianFormat = getAudioFormat();
AudioInputStream converted = 
AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(littleEndianFormat, ais);
}
```

please any solution for passing the number what i write it to audio file to play audio name thanks

Comment: Since you're using JavaFX, why not use the `javafx.scene.media` API for playing the audio?

Comment: do you have example code dear @Slaw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@FXML
    private TextField numberscreen;

public void AudioPlay() {
        filestring = new File("src\\audio\\" + numberscreen.getText().trim() + ".wav");
        Media file = new Media(filestring.toURI().toString());

        mp = new MediaPlayer(file);

        mp.setOnReady(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Duration: " + file.getDuration().toMinutes());
                // display media's metadata
                file.getMetadata().entrySet().forEach((entry) -> {
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
                    mp.seek(Duration.millis(200));
                });
                mp.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mp.stop();
                        if (mp.isAutoPlay()) {
                            //Plays the subsequent files
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                });
                // play if you want
                mp.play();

            }
        });

    }
```

this the solution what i need it i solved the problem i found it by myself